# How to Convert Array or String in Snowflake to Timestamp_NTZ

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, string-formatting, sql-timestamp

I currently have some incoming datestamps as from outside datasource, but am struggling to define them in a table through my Snowflake Tables.

The column is formatted as such: `{"type":"TEXT","length":12,"byteLength":48,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}`

The only current workaround I have is this convoluted code.

```
SELECT timestamp_ntz_from_parts(
            GET(strtok_to_array(CONCAT('20',array_to_string(
                             regexp_substr_all('220530161501', '[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]', 1, 1),',')),','),0)::DOUBLE,
                               .......);
```

Any suggestions to convert string to integer for timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format of input  'YYMMDDHH24MISS' and first `22` stands for `2022`:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ( '220530161501', 'YYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's literally incredible. Thank you.
I had similar but was missing the 24 for HH format